# JPA GenerationType.IDENTITY not considering column with auto increment in MS SQL

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I have a table with a simple int id column with Identity auto increment in SQL Server.

```
    USE [Hot]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[InstagramRequest]    Script Date: 24.10.2015 18:49:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InstagramRequest](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [instUserId] [int] NULL,
    [request] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [intime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InstagramRequest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 10) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InstagramRequest] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_InstagramRequest_intime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [intime]
GO
```

Entity class is ;

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author z
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "InstagramRequest")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "InstagramRequest.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM InstagramRequest i"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "InstagramRequest.findById", query = "SELECT i FROM InstagramRequest i WHERE i.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "InstagramRequest.findByInstUserID", query = "SELECT i FROM InstagramRequest i WHERE i.instUserID = :instUserID"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "InstagramRequest.findByIntime", query = "SELECT i FROM InstagramRequest i WHERE i.intime = :intime")})
public class InstagramRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "instUserID")
    private Integer instUserID;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "request")
    private String request;
    @Column(name = "intime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date intime;

    public InstagramRequest() {
    }

    public InstagramRequest(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getInstUserID() {
        return instUserID;
    }

    public void setInstUserID(Integer instUserID) {
        this.instUserID = instUserID;
    }

    public String getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(String request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public Date getIntime() {
        return intime;
    }

    public void setIntime(Date intime) {
        this.intime = intime;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof InstagramRequest)) {
            return false;
        }
        InstagramRequest other = (InstagramRequest) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.instagramparse.entity.InstagramRequest[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

The error message is as below .;

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'master.dbo.InstagramRequest'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
Error Code: 515
Call: INSERT INTO InstagramRequest (instUserID, intime, request) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.instagramparse.entity.InstagramRequest[ id=null ])

Which GenerationType should I use in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `GenerationType` is correct. You need to remove `@Basic(optional = false)` - it does not make sense to enforce that this field is set by JPA if it is to be autogenerated by the DB.

In fact, what seems to happen is that your JPA provider tries to insert NULL value instead of not setting anything for the id column. As the column is autogenerated, no value can be inserted into that column in an `INSERT`. Making the field optional will work as expected - JPA will not try to insert any value for I'd into the db, but will read the generated value after insert, making the value to always be non-null after persist.

Comment: I removed `@Basic(optional = false)` but the result is not changed. I got the same error.

Comment: I cannot make the field optional because it is the primary key and also uniqe IDENTITY

Comment: It doesn't "try to insert NULL". It doesn't provide it ("ID") in the INSERT statement, hence leaving it to the datastore to set it

Comment: It is already leaved to datastore namely generation type identity set. Could you open it a bit more what do you mean leaving it datastore

Comment: I'm sorry, my answer was wrong as I thought that `id` field is mapped to `instUserID`. But there is another field in your entity named `instUserID`. The problem is that it has null value, but your DB table does not allow NULL values for that column. You need either to set a value before persisting, or allow NULL values.

Comment: 'InstUserID' allows null as mentioned in my post create table code. And also I passed the value to the 'instUserId' while inserting. The focussed issue in here is generation type identity does not work

Comment: I cannot allows null to the column 'ID' because of being primary key! And also I do not pass any vallue to the ID Field I expected that value from the generation type IDENTITY

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a harsh judgment and did not read carefully enough the error message. Now, it appears that your mapping and your code is correct, but the DB does not generate the ID automatically and requires that a not null value is inserted. Can you check the table in the DB, if the ID column is autoincremented? Can you insert a record into the table direct via SQL manager?

Comment: I did it manually via the SQL manager and  inserted successfully.

`USE [Hot]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[InstagramRequest]
           ([instUserId]
           ,[request]
           )
     VALUES
           (1,
           'test'
           )
GO `
**(1 row(s) affected)**

Comment: I solved the problem by updating the JPA version :) thank you to you all

Comment: It seems you are using different DBs from JPA than from the SQL script. JPA uses `master`, but your script uses `Hot`. Which one is correct? Either fix your datasource to point to correct DB, or fix your DB to autoincrement values in ID column.

Comment: I wonder which JPA provider and which version made the problem, and which version than fixed it. Would you let us know? Just curious, if it may happen to me also :)

Comment: I updted the **eclipselink-2.1.0.v201304241213** to the **eclipselink-2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3**